# React useState how it works? How can It be with vanila js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Want to understand, how it can be built with pure js.
I expect it something like that:

```
const useStatePureJs = () => {
  let state = null;
  
  const setState = (value) => {
    state = value
  };

  return [
    state,
    setState
  ];
};

const [state, setState] = useStatePureJs();

setState(5);

console.log(state);
```

But ofc my console.log will return null, because of scope initialization.
How I can make it be updated with pure js implemetation? Value I mean.
Do I need a watcher or something?

Comment: `initialState` is not null by default in `useState()`.

Comment: yes, but it won't update the value after setter called. so initial state is not the problem

Comment: Why not check the actual [implementation](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/41c5d00fc90734822e915a6a268a24c9726828a5/packages/react-debug-tools/src/ReactDebugHooks.js#L128) if you are not sure about how it works?

Comment: thank you, but there some 'noize' with references to memorization and checking if initialState is a function. It doesn't really clear to have a complete picture of how it can be done with just js. Yes, I can make it works if state will be wrapped into a closure, but in this case I would need to call it as a fucnction, not a value...

Answer (score 0):

What about this? 
Seems to work as you would expect.

```js
const useStatePureJs = () => {
  let state;
  const getState = () => {
    return state
  }
  const setState = (x) => {
    state = x
  }
  return [ getState, setState ]
}

const [ getState, setState ] = useStatePureJs()
setState(1)
console.log(getState()) // 1
setState(2)
console.log(getState()) // 2
```

Comment: not really. The point - we need to use the value as a variable, not a function call.
so getState - as in react. not getState()